# How can I initialize class in a separate thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a class storedetails which get different values from database. fetching these values from database and calculating takes a long time(due to poor design of the database over 76 different queries for one store).

My implementation for generating the report is as below.

```
string week = "32";
string year = "2013";
string[] storecode = getallstoreforweekandyear(week, year); // get all store code that were active for the week and year
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
foreach (string item in storecode)
{
    storedetails sd = new storedetails(item, year, week);// this initializion I want to move to another thread because it is taking time.
    ar.Add(sd);
}

ar.TrimToSize();
DataTable dt = getdtfromarraylist(ar);// convert the arraylist of class to datatable
     Gridview1.Datasourc=dt;
```

My implementation of class is in over 2000 line of code

```
class storedetails
{
    public storedetails(string store,string year, string week)
{ 

//time taking implementation
}
}
```

Is it possible that initialization of classes occur in separate threads, so I can gain some speed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Task Parallel Libraries in .NET 4.0 - they simplify threading a lot.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
object locker = new object();
Parallel.ForEach (storecode => item
     {
          storedetails sd = new storedetails(item, year, week);
          lock(locker)
          {
              ar.Add(sd);
          }
     });
```